# Как происходит очищение памяти из под объектов Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, классы, память

Допустим, я создал указатель на класс Кнопки внутри другого класса Окна, потом выделил под нее память. 
Как мне высвободить память потом из под кнопки? 
Переопределить метод класса закрытия Окна и там высвободить?
Или указать родителем Окно через this и она автоматически высвободится?
+ еще как высвобождать память из под контейнеров?
Буду очень признателен за хорошее объяснение)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно указать родителем кнопки окно или другой объект, который наследник QObject и он удаляется когда нужно. Для контейнеров можно умные указатели применить.

Comment: lastWindow = new QDialog();
textLayout = new QVBoxLayout(lastWindow);
textEdit = new QTextEdit(lastWindow); Вот так можно? Если хочу внутри одного окна открыть другое небольшое

Comment: да, вроде должно быть нормально.

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой код вполне будет работать.

```
lastWindow = new QDialog();
textLayout = new QVBoxLayout(lastWindow);
textEdit = new QTextEdit(lastWindow);
```

Только не забудьте удалить верхний экземпляр класса

```
delete lastWindow;
```

Т.к. у textLayout и textEdit указан родителем lastWindow, то при его удалении будут удалены также и они. Кроме того не забудьте о присвоении layout при процедурном создании формы. Должно получится както так.

```
lastWindow = new QDialog();
textLayout = new QVBoxLayout(lastWindow);
lastWindow->setLayout(textLayout);
textEdit = new QTextEdit(lastWindow);
textLayout->addItem(textEdit);
```